# Members vs. Organizations

Tags: trello, trello-organization

I have a board with members who should be able to add and change cards on the board. I have an organization of business partners whom I'd like to be able to see, but not change the contents of the board. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

If the board is under the same organization, your profile for the board should be

- Visibility - Organization
- Voting - However you wish
- Comments - Members
- Adding Members - Admin
- Allow organization members to add themselves to this board - disabled

If the organization is different keep all other settings but  change Visibility to Public

They will not be able to hard link the separate organizations together so you are just going to have to give your business partners the url to the board.